# GetLastError() returns ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE after call to PeekNamedPipe only when using message mode

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I can't figure out why this is happening... I have a Named Pipe server and client application. Both are in read/write mode and transfer data between each other. The server has two threads, one that reads from the pipe and one that writes to it. While the client is writing a bunch of messages, the server's read thread will exit because it's call to PeekNamedPipe is returning false. The return value of GetLastError() is ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE. Neither thread in the server is closing the pipe, and the client is still writing to the pipe, so I don't understand why the pipe is "broken."

If I change the server to BYTE mode, then everything works flawlessly. I am really wanting to use Message mode though so my "messages" do not get grouped together.

*If I change the client to BYTE mode and the server to Message mode, it works.*

Call to CreateNamedPipe

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    pszPipeName,
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    PIPE_WAIT | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE,
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
    dwOutBufferSize,
    dwInBufferSize,
    0,
    NULL);
```

Call to PeekNamedPipe

```
while( RunningState == DDCMP_STATE_RUNNING )
{
    if( !PeekNamedPipe(hPipe,NULL,NULL,NULL,&dwBytesAvailable,NULL) || !dwBytesAvailable )
        if( GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE || GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED || GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE )
            break;
        else
        {
            Sleep( 100 );
            continue;
        }

    //call to ReadFile(hPipe,...) with dwBytesAvailable as size, and then processing of data
}
```

Comment: Are you calling ConnectNamedPipe anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `GetLastError()` not only when `PeekNamedPipe()` fails, but also when it succeeds and returns 0 bytes.  You should not be calling `GetLastError()` in that latter case, as the value will not be meaningful.  Use it more like this instead:

```
while( RunningState == DDCMP_STATE_RUNNING ) 
{ 
    if( !PeekNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL, NULL, NULL, &dwBytesAvailable, NULL) )
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();

        if( (dwError == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) ||
            (dwError == ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED) ||
            (dwError == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) )
        { 
            break;
        }

        dwBytesAvailable = 0;
    }

    if( !dwBytesAvailable )
    {
        Sleep(100);
        continue;
    }

    //call to ReadFile(hPipe,...) with dwBytesAvailable as size, and then processing of data 
}
```

Comment: If `PeekNamedPipe(...)` returns `true`, then shouldn't `GetLastError()` return `ERROR_SUCCESS`?

Comment: This did not resolve the issue. `PeekNamedPipe()` is returning `false`, and `GetLastError()` is returning `ERROR_PIPE_BROKEN`.

Comment: Most API functions (including `PeekNamedPipe()`) DO NOT update `GetLastError()` on success, unless they are specifically documented to do so (which `PeekNamedPipe()` is not). GetLastError() is updated on success only when an API's return value needs further clarification based on context (see `GetFileSize()` for example).

Comment: If `PeekNamedPipe` returns false and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` then the pipe really is gone. Either the OS lost the connection internally, or the client accidentally closed the pipe when you were not expecting it. Check your client code for similar logic bugs, and add some logging when your code is closing the pipe so you can see who is doing it and when.

Comment: This answer is exactly why I asked if you're calling ConnectNamedPipe.  It appears you're trying to read from the pipe before a client has connected.